# Discrete variables as inputs vs Continuous variable as output

Tags: regression, machine-learning, correlation, mathematical-statistics

I have 3 input variables which all boolean i.e 0 or 1. And the output/target variable is the continuous variable. The objective is to model the correlations among these input discrete variables and the output continuous variable. Is multiple linear regression still can be used?

The scenario is we have got many controllers to switch on and off which affects out energy consumption. Thus the main inputs all have either 1 or 0.